# How to initiate a remote SVN update on server

Tags: svn

I'm using SVN for a project, and for easy deployments to the server we're just using another SVN enlistment there.  So I've been using Remote Desktop to log onto the server and then trigger an update (we use Tortoise SVN).

Is there an existing tool (or SVN feature) that would allow me to trigger this update without logging on to the server and doing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like ChrisH says, this might be overkill, but [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) or its equivalents in other platforms is remarkably easy to set up for a simple SVN update.  It would also be simple enough to include an Ant script or other build bits into the process if you need them.

Comment: Actually this is a great suggestion.  Easy to set up and also allows me to extend it later if I want to create a real build system or perform some other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill, but [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) could certainly do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use:

**1. create a post-commit hook to update your copy**

http://www.codersrevolution.com/index.cfm/2008/9/15/Creating-a-postcommit-hook-for-Subversion

**2. use sharpsvn lib to automate your update process**

http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/servlets/ProjectProcess?documentContainer=c4__Samples&view

by using the above approaches, you do not need to log onto your remote server to update your copy manually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  The sharpsvn lib looks useful.